# How to Click a Button with PyWinAuto

Tags: python, button, click, pywinauto

I am trying to do something (I think) should simple I am trying to select a button named "Start".  I have been looking for documentation that describes how-to click a button (with descent example).  I have been unable to find any.  Anyway here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Scripts\TestVBApp2.py", line 18, in <module>
vbButton1 = ButtonWrapper(vbapp.Button.WrapperObject("Start")).Click
TypeError: WrapperObject() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is the code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from time import sleep
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import ButtonWrapper
import pyautogui
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True

app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\VBPrograms\\SimpleWPFApp.exe"')
app.MainWindow.Wait('ready')
vbapp = app.window_(title_re="MainWindow")
vbButton1 = ButtonWrapper(vbapp.Button.WrapperObject("Start")).Click
```

Attached is a screenshot of the app with the "Start" button.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use app.vbapp.print_control_identifiers().  The response was the were None.

Comment: pywinauto 0.5.4 doesn't support WPF (any controls on the window are not visible, you can check it with Spy++). But fortunately we're preparing new release 0.6.0 having MS UI Automation support. Are you interested in early testing?

Comment: Yes, I will be an early tester for WPF. Just let me know. Do you need my email address.  I have 2 programs: one is WPF, and the other is 32-bit program.  Is there a good example that I can look at ?  What do I need for 32-bit button click?

Comment: Install UIA branch by `pip install -U https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/UIA.zip` Examples for Notepad and explorer.exe are in [README prototype](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/0.6.0-README-prototype).

Comment: You can leave your feedback in [Gitter room](https://gitter.im/pywinauto/pywinauto?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge) or just submit an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Vasily,  I receive "404 error - File Not Found" after entering "pip install -U https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/UIA.zip". Is the path correct ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct except trailing "&quot;" symbols you've pasted into the comment. Is it the reason?

Comment: As an alternative you can download it by the URL, unpack and run "python setup.py install".

Comment: Actually `https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/archive/master.zip` is more up-to-date (have Tree wrapper just implemented).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the last line into `vbapp.Start.click()`

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.